# How to properly get the info from the arrays so is possible to insert in database?

Tags: php

After a user fill a form to register two participants in the conference and click in "Register", there is an array with the request data.

The request data has the array `name` that stores the name of the participant being registered in the registration_type_id "1" (Jake) and the name of the participant being registered in the registration_type_id "4" (John).

The same for the `surname` array, this surname array stores each surname for each registration type.

And the same for the `answer` array that stores each answer for each registration type.

```
 "name" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "Jake"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "John"
        ]
      ]
      "surname" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "W"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "K"
        ]
      ]
      "answer" => array:1 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => array:6 [▼
            1 => "answer1"
            2 => "answer2"
          ]
        ]
      ]
```

**Doubt:** My doubt is how to get the info from this array structure above in order to store each participant in the participants table and also how to store each answer in the answers table.

With the array content above the participants table should stay like:

```
 id      registration_type_id                name             surname        registration_id
 1            1                            Jake                 W                 1 
 2            4                           John                 K                 1
```

The answers table should stay like:

```
 id       participant_id          question_id        answer
     1              1                  1              answer1
     1              1                  2              answer2
```

Do you know how to properly achieve that?

I have the code below that first insert an entry in the registrations table to store the registration:

```
# user object
$user = Auth::user();
# add registration to Database
$registration = Registration::create([
    'conference_id' => $id,
    'user_that_did_registration' => $user->id]
);
```

But then is necessary to store  each participant in the articipants table and also each answer in the answers table. Do you know how to properly get the necessary info from the above array to store in the participants table and in the answers table with the code below?

To insert in the participants table it is necessary to use:

```
$participant_result = Participant::create([
      'name' => how to get the name of each participant from the array?,
      'surname' => how to get the surname of each participant from the array?,
      'registration_id' => $registration->id,
      'registration_type_id' => how to get the registration_type_id from the array?
  ]);
```

To insert in the answers table it is necessary to use:

```
 $answer = Answer::create([
        'question_id' => how to get each question id from the array?,
        'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
        'answer' => how to  get each answer from the array?
    ]);
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your project, but I feel like you have extra/unnecessary levels in your input array.  I also don't know why your keys start at 1.  Do you simply need a way to traverse the array? How close does this get you?  https://3v4l.org/bEYlM

Comment: Thanks, but so for example in the participants table is necessary to store the name, surname and registration type id, is necessary 3 foreachs, one to get the name other the surname and other the registration_type _id of each participant?

Comment: The array has index 1 and 4 because are the registration types where the user is doing a registration, the user is doing a registration in a conference and for the registration he selected the quantity "1" for the registration type with id "1" and the quantity "1" for the registration type with id 4.

Comment: For example the array name stores the name of the participant being registered  in  the registration_type_id "1" (Jake) and the name of the  participant being registered in the registration_type_id "4" (John): "name" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼ 
          1 => "Jake"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "John"
        ]
      ]". The same for the surname, stores each surname for each registration ype, and the same for the answer array that stores each answer for each registration type.

Comment: Like that it seems that is possible to store the name and surname of each participant. But how to get the registration_type_id of each participant? "foreach ($request->all()['name'] as $key => $name) { $participant_result = Participant::create([  'name' => $name[1], 'surname' => $request['surname'][$key][1], 'registration_id' => $registration->id, 'registration_type_id' => how to get this???
 ]); }".

Comment: The registration_tpye_id for the participant Jake is "1" and for John is "4", as it is in the array:
    
 "name" => array:2 [▼
                    1 => array:1 [▼
                      1 => "Jake"
                    ]
                    4 => array:1 [▼
                      1 => "John"
                    ]
                  ]
                  "surname" => array:2 [▼
                    1 => array:1 [▼
                      1 => "W"
                    ]
                    4 => array:1 [▼
                      1 => "K"
                    ]
                  ].

Comment: `registration_type_id = $key` right?

Comment: For example in the array name:  "name" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "Jake"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "John"
        ]
      ]",  the  participant "Jake" is being registered is the registration type with id 1, the participant John is being registered in the registration type with id 4, so there are the indexes 1 and 4, so the name array stores the info considering that, the registration type where each participant is being registered.

Comment: To store in the participants table it works like " foreach ($request->all()['rname'] as $key => $nameArray) {
            foreach ($nameArray as $nameKey => $name) {

                $participant_result = Participant::create([
                    'name'                 => $name,
                    'surname'              => $request['rsurname'][$key][$nameKey],
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'registration_type_id' => $key
           ]);  }  }", but to store in the answers table Im not understanding how to get the question id and answer.